# Why isn't Fabric running my deployment in parallel when I use the -P command line option?

Tags: fabric

I'm running Fabric on Debian out of virtualenv to deploy a project to multiple remote Debian servers. When I run the command to deploy to a single server:

```
time .venv/bin/fabric server1 deploy
```

The `server1` command sets the remote host. Deployment, which pulls code out of a repository and builds a virtualenv for the project on the remote server, takes about 7 minutes:

```
real    7m49.881s
user    0m52.883s
sys     0m18.345s
```

I configured passwordless SSH access to 3 servers and now run fabric with the `-P` command:

```
.venv/bin/fabric parallel deploy
```

The `parallel` command assigns 3 servers to env.hosts. Deployment takes 3 times as long:

```
real   22m22.259s
user    2m45.718s
sys     0m53.827s
```

I used the `-P` option after reading the Fabric documentation on [parallel execution](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/parallel.html).

Comment: add you fabfile, or an accurate approximation there of

Comment: Can't really help if you don't provide more information :/